# Symfony2 + PHP Facebook Api

Tags: facebook, symfony

I'm trying to use the Facebook API for PHP in a Symfony2 Bundle.

My problem is how to include these Classes in my Bundle.

In my autoload file I have included the namespace **DIR**.'/../vendor/facebook/src', but it still doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: What doesn't work? Please provide any errors you're seeing.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `FOSFacebookBundle` for all your `facebook` needs.

The bundle can be found here:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle

If this bundle doesn't help you then just add this to the bottom of your `autoload.php`

```
//Loading facebook from vendor
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/facebook/src/facebook.php';
```

Then within the controller call:

```
$facebook = new \Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to make FOSFacebookBundle work with my project a lot of time, but it was impossible. I only need one functionality of Facebook, connect the user and retrive the e-mail of the user. Thanks!

Comment: This work if you add "require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/facebook/src/facebook.php';" to the autoload file that is in the vendor folder of Symfony

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Composer - add to your composer.json:

```
{
  "require" : {
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*"
  }
}
```

More info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted